# Clearing Tasks Airflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm working with Python3 and Airflow. I've a daily process that has some individual task that fails sometimes.

I would like to know, if someone knows, how to get a list of the failed tasks, at least at the end of the process. I could change my code. I could somehow return a dict with every task name and their result, but I think it has to be an easier way.

Once the process has "finished", I want it to **clear those tasks** state(I mean, Failed and Upstream Failed tasks) **and retry them** automatically.

I've read about something about:

```
airflow clear -t task_name <dag_name>
```

So think I just have to iterate over the task names clearing them, but I need to know who they are.

Lots of thanks!

Comment: Why would you do that and not set retries and the retry interval on the task? Is there a special requirement that this has to happen at the end of the whole run?

Comment: A part of the process is downloading some files that are being uploaded to a server. I think that some files aren't fully uploaded and process fails in the moment of the download. It's not a problem for me waiting until the end of the process to retry those downloads(there are other tasks that my process is doing, not downloading one file is not a stopper for me), but it's not necessary. I prefer retrying this after the whole process finishes.

Comment: I do not understand what the advantage is of doing so and not treating a task as an atomic event which can restart itself. Also, retrying immediately after a fail is implemented in Airflow, your way - I have not heard of but it might be possible.

Comment: If I would do what you are telling me, for what I know, I would have to change almost every task instance (_all task instances that might fail_) in my DAG with the retry parameter. If I'm waiting for a file to be uploaded, retrying at the end of the whole process gives me the advantage that it's almost sure that I've waited enough time for it to finish the full upload. If I could get the list of failed tasks, I just have to do an iteration and not changing every task instance that might fail.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I am still not sure if this is possible with Airflow.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are downloading the file, but you could add a sensor task prior to the download task.  The sensor task would wait until the file is available  to download before it allows the upstream task to start.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me I would write my own Python script which interfaces with Airflow by loading up its models (`airflow.models.TaskInstance`), and database connection `airflow.settings.Session`, locating the failed tasks and then clearing them through the script. Airflow already has code for clearing tasks that may offer a helpful starting point.